# Replace #ifdefs in C# DLL

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll

I have a C++ DLL which has #defines used like (these defines are automatically defined based on the build configuration, e.g. Debug, Release, etc)

```
#if defined(CONSTANT)
..
// Some code
#else
// Some other code
```

I need same functionality in C# dll.
Is it ok if I define some global constants in C# dll and use them
instead of defines?
e.g.

```
if(Globals.SomeConstant == SOMEVALUE)
// Do this
else
// Do smth else
```

Then when I want to ship the DLL I will **in advance** (probably as a default value during declaration) assign `SOMEVALUE` to `Globals.SomeConstant` - will this work this way? (Depending on which configuration I need).

I saw some similar questions but they weren't about DLLs.

Comment: Why not use proper C# `#if DEBUG ... #endif` style code then? It works the same way as C++.

Comment: @DavidG: It's not only DEBUG constant they define some other constants too. PS I thought there were no defines in C#

Comment: The DEBUG constant is just defined in the build properties, you can add your own too. So yes, they do exists in C#.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/4y6tbswk.aspx

Comment: @DavidG: How to add my own constants? So I just add them inside DLL? It will work same way?

Comment: Project properties, Build tab, Conditional compilation symbols

Comment: Note that DEBUG and TRACE are simply added with the checkboxes below that.

Comment: @DavidG: I can define constants manually as well I believe?

Comment: Yes, like I said in the [comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32987514/replace-ifdefs-in-c-sharp-dll#comment53799963_32987514).

Comment: @DavidG: That is via properties but I can't I do it from code? So that all other classes can see it?

Comment: You can use [`#define`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt3yck0x.aspx) also

Comment: @DavidG: And if I do it in one class any other class will see it?

Comment: I linked you the documentation, did you even read it?

Comment: @DavidG: Yes, and see what it says "The scope of a symbol that was created by using #define is the file in which the symbol was defined." - this I don't want. I need the symbol to be visible through whole project

Comment: @DavidG: It seems it is not possible to define by code symbols which are visible in whole project. In that case do you think my above approach with constants in classes is bad? (Also if I define those symbols in project properties, do I need to ship some additional config file with the DLL which contains those symbols?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it similarly as in c++

You can define / undefine them in your source code or as a conditional compilation symbol. In visual studio this can be done using *Solution Explorer - Properties - Build - conditional compilation symbols*

However, nowadays people tend to use a configuration file for these constants. This way, you don't have to recompile your source code nor redistribute it to change the behaviour.

The most easy method is via visual studio *solution explorer - properties - settings*

You can add settings for most types. Booleans come closest to #define. Using an int can give you more than two possibilities. See the difficulties if you wanted to be able to use several values for a TimeSpan or an URI using #define.

The nice thing about using the settings is that a class is generated for you to easily access the settings.

Another method is to read the config file directly using the [System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) class. This gives you more freedom about the format of the configuration. The disadvantage is that you have to convert the read values into proper types yourself, inclusive handling errors if the value can't be read.

Summarized: advantages of the config file method:

- No need to change source files
- No need to recompile
- No need to re-install
- only change the config file on those machines that need the change
- improved type safety

Comment: See what doc says "The scope of a symbol that was created by using #define is the file in which the symbol was defined.". I want symbol to be visible in whole project and define in code. Can't I do this? (I will think about your suggestion bug I might go with defines now)

Comment: Because of this scope you should not #define the symbol within a file but as a "Conditional Compilation Symbol" per project. Be aware though: there is no guarantee that the conditional compilation symbol is the same for all projects in your solution. This will hinder reuse of your DLLs by other solutions that want different conditional compilation symbols. Another reason to consider a config file.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more what you mean with all projects in solution? I am beginner with .NET. Also, since situation is like this, what if I use the approach I showed in my question? Is it problematic or it works and is not elegant? Further if I define the symbols in project properties, it will be visible to all classes, but do I need to supply some additional file with the DLL then for these defines to work?

Comment: A bit difficult without the possibility of formatting. I asume you know what a DLL is. Suppose you have several DLLs: A.Dll, B.DLL and C.DLL. You have two executable programs, one that uses A.Dll and B.DLL, let's call it AB.EXE and one that uses A.DLL and C.DLL named AC.DLL.

Comment: In my case I have one DLL. Please comment what you think about my approach in question using public const values instead? Also if I use defines in project settings, do I need to additionally ship some file with my DLL?

Comment: const values is very similar as config file, except you'll have to recompile to change the value from say configurationA to configurationB. Your Dll already has file app.config, which is fairly readable text file. Try creating a solution with two projects: a dll and an executable that uses the dll. Use project properties of the dll to create a setting (what you call public constant), for instance MyCreatedSetting. Access the setting in your dll: myConstant = Properties.Settings.Default.MyCreatedSetting. Find setting in both app.configs. See what happens if you change the one in EXE

Comment: I think I am not following you because I am beginner with .NET. Anyway is the solution with public constants (`if(Globals.SomeConstant == SOMEVALUE)`) such as I described in my question fine ?? recompiling is not problem because currently it works like this with defines anyway. Or I guess I will have to ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer lead to a more questions than it answered. Hence I thought an example would help.

Suppose I have a DLL, called MyDll. It has a configuration setting that in really old times would have been defined using #define.

My C-synctax is a bit rusty, but it would look like:

```
#define UseAlternateGreeting
public class MyClass
{
    public string GetGreeting()
    {
        #if defined UseAlternateGreeting
            return "Hello World!";
        #else
            return "Here I am!";
        #endif
    }
}
```

Now suppose we have several programs that use this DLL. Program! wants to use the default setting. However Program2 wants to use the alternate setting. There is no way to solve this.

Besides if we want to change the value of the setting we have to recompile and redistribute everything to everyone.

**Wouldn't it be easier if we could just edit a file with notepad to change the string?**

Luckily Microsoft also saw the advantage of this. Over more than 10 years we have the idea of configuration files. Assemblies have a config file with the name of the application and the extension **config**. This file can easily be edited using any text editor by those who know what the configuration items mean.

If we replace the #define with an item in the config file the greeting could be changed to the alternate greeting without having to recompile and redistribute the whole program.

Luckily Visual Studio helps us a lot when creating the config file.

**Preparations**

- Let Visual Studio Create a console application in a new Solution: name the program *ConfigExample*
- Add a new Library to this application, name it *MyDll*
- View the properties of MyDll
- Add a *Setting*.

  - Name: MySetting,
  - Type: string,
  - Scope: application,
  - Value: Hello World! (without string quotes)
- In project MyDll create a class *MyClass*

  public class MyClass
  {
      public string GetText()
      {
          return Properties.Settings.Default.MySetting;
      }
  }
- Go to project ConfigExample
- Project Add reference to MyDll (via tab page solution)
- Use the code in your main:

  using MyDll;
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      var obj = new MyClass();
      var txt = obj.GetText();
      Console.WriteLine(txt);
  }

Compile and run, and you'll see the proper text displayed. If you go to the debug / bin directory of the program you'll find a text file *ConfigExample.config*. Open it in a text editor and you'll see... nothing abut hello world!

This means that your program is not really interested in a special setting, the  setting that was default the time that MyDll was built may be used.

However, if you want to use a special setting,

- In visual Studio, Go to project MyDll
- open file app.config
- a.o. you'll find the following

(to prevent the editor interfering with the formatting, I added an apostrophe to each line)

```
'</configSections>
'<applicationSettings>
   '<MyDll.Properties.Settings>
        '<setting name="MySetting" serializeAs="String">
            '<value>Hello World!</value>
        '</setting>
    '</MyDll.Properties.Settings>
'</applicationSettings>
```

- Copy paste this part to *ConfigExample.Config*
- for all already distributed programs do this in the folder where the executable is (in your case: debug/bin)
- for all ConfigExample programs that will be built in the future do this in visual studio in App.Config of the ConfigExample project.

The result will be as follows:

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
'<configuration>
'    <configSections>
'        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings"     type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        <section name="MyDll.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
'        </sectionGroup>
'    </configSections>
'    <applicationSettings>
'        <MyDll.Properties.Settings>
'            <setting name="MySetting" serializeAs="String">
'                <value>Hello World!</value>
'            </setting>
'        </MyDll.Properties.Settings>
'    </applicationSettings>
'   
'   <startup> 
'        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"     />
'    </startup>

'</configuration>
```

Now all we have to do is change the Hello World into an alternat greeting

```
'        <MyDll.Properties.Settings>
'            <setting name="MySetting" serializeAs="String">
'                <value>Here I am!</value>
'            </setting>
'        </MyDll.Properties.Settings>
```

Run the program without building it and you'll see that the new value is used.

Advantages:
 - It works with a lot of types that can be assigned from string - Type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(string)). Visual Studio already supports a lot of types including TimeSpan and DateTime. 
 - You don't have to recompile your source code to change the value
 - Several executables can use their own configuration setting: one program could use the original greeting, the other can use the alternate one
 - If your program doesn't provide a value in the config file the default value is used.
 - You don't have to read the configuration yourself.
 - It is type safe: if you say it is a TimeSpan, then you have to do some serious typing to confuse it with for example an integer.

Well there is a lot more to be said about configuration, you can even have a configuration per user. But that's far outside your question about alternatives for plain C #define

Comment: Can you please explain what you meant here:  "Be aware though: there is no guarantee that the conditional compilation symbol is the same for all projects in your solution. This will hinder reuse of your DLLs by other solutions that want different conditional compilation symbols." - I am thinking to use #defines and your comment is making me stop from it. Please explain in beginner language what does that mean and in which case it can cause problem?

Comment: My! I have to work for my points! Suppose you have a DLL with two projects, let's say a DLL and an executable that uses the DLL. In your DLL project the conditional compilation symbol MAXFILELENGTH is set to 10, but in the executable project it is set to 100. This means that your executable thinks that your DLL can handle fileLengths up to 100, while in fact it can only handle FILELENGTHS to 10. There is no way one project can ask the other for its #define. So you to manually make sure they are equal. Using a config file the executable can ask the DLL: What is your maximum file length?

Comment: See in my DLL I am using the symbols to compile different code based on the value of the symbol (or #define in C++). So, if symbol PHYSICAL_HASP is defined I execute one code, if not other. Now, if I hard code this logic in C# using #ifdefs, what problems may I encounter?

Comment: If you don't need the #define outside the project, then this is not a problem. The problem arises if you need the same value of a #define in several projects

Comment: "Now suppose we have several programs that use this DLL. Program! wants to use the default setting. However Program2 wants to use the alternate setting. " Here do you mean other projects *use*  it before or after compilation?

Comment: It has nothing to do with before and after compilation. When using a config file you don't have to recompile if you want to change the value of the constant. You don't need access to the source code (suppose you bought the DLL), nor a compiler for the code. just a text editor to change the config file.

Comment: I am not refering to config file. I am refering to #ifs, and the problem you mentioned with those #ifs. So.. "Now suppose we have several programs that use this DLL. Program! wants to use the default setting. However Program2 wants to use the alternate setting. " Here do you mean other projects use it (the compilation symbol) before or after compilation?