# Use #if in C# DLL

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have a C# dll and I plan to write code with #ifs inside, e.g

```
#if Constant
//do smth
#else
```

I know that then I need to add the `Constant` to my project settings, build and `Conditional compilation symbols`.

Then in another application I want to use this DLL.

But I was told about this approach:

> "Be aware though: there is no guarantee that the conditional
>   compilation symbol is the same for all projects in your solution. This
>   will hinder reuse of your DLLs by other solutions that want different
>   conditional compilation symbols."

I don't understand what is meant here. I am beginner with .NET. Can you please explain what is meant above and what problems may I encounter if I use #ifs inside my C# dll?

I only have one project in my solution and later I will give my DLL to other people who will use it in their program.

**Update**:  So is not the compilation symbol embedded inside the DLL? If project A wants to use this DLL, should project A also define the compilation symbol?

Comment: Can you provide context to that quote? Is it something you saw online?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: It will be hard:( that was a comment to me on a related question

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: it's a comment to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32988038/580053

Comment: @quser: why don't ask the author, what he means? From my point, this is a very strange conclusion. First, one can't define conditional compilation symbols at the solution level (except build configurations). Second, if you define symbol at the project level, it will be there, regardless of solutions, which use this project, and other projects in solutions. The only problem with conditional compilation is the different output, depending on conditions.

Comment: @Dennis: I asked and could not understand his explanation. So is not the compilation symbol embedded inside the DLL? If project A wants to use this DLL, should project A ALSO define the compilation symbol on which DLL relies?

Comment: There is no compilation symbol involved, only a flag. Both in C++ and C#, this means that the code guarded by that `#if#` won't even be compiled. It will be removed from the source code before the compiler ever sees it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Will I achieve same functionality if I use public const flags (say of type int) instead? what problems can it have if there optimizations on? please see comment below under the asnwer

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Can you please just answer me what if I use public const bools instead, I just want different code to be run, depending which flag I set. that is it. What problems you mentioned if optimizations are on?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Can you please just answer me what if I use public const bools instead, I just want different code to be run, depending which flag I set. that is it. What problems you mentioned if optimizations are on?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: So what shall I do if I want to replicate the functionality of #idefs as in C++ in my C# code? Which approach to use? I don't want to change anything at runtime

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Ok I will do that so you can bring back your answer which was nice

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: if someConstFlag is false, why would be the clause which is run when someConstFlag is true is removed?

Comment: You need to post a question with the actual question you want the answer to. If you then want the answer to a new question, you should post that as a new question.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: why? you already told me I can use #ifs to duplicate behaviour of C++ ifdefs in my C# program (isn't it?), so your old answer holds, no?